# OFDM to transmit and receive multiple tones with different frequencies

Tags: java, android

I was generating a single frequency tone on on android application and receiving it on another android application (on another device).

Now, I am moving to generate multiple tone with different frequencies, I guess I need OFDM for the transmission and reception.

However, I am not fom a strong communication background and I know only the bascis of OFDM (I checked many videos).

Any idea about the required steps (please explain in simple way and with details for easy implementation), since I am not finding many related sources else than Matlab while I want it in java